# Sharepoint integration with other Document management System

Tags: sharepoint-integration

can any one help me with the logic of how to go about integrating sharepoint with other DMS?
for eg, if i upload some document in DMS,  same should be Syncd with sharepoint and vice versa. is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: This seems to be a very broad question, I think you need to provide more details. I mean, sure, everything is possible, but it very hard to tell you how without more information

Comment: I am asking for the logic itself. i only doesnt have clue of how to go about.

Answer (score 0):

It depend which DMS you are trying to integrate. Normally now a days every application have a connector to sync or work with sharepoint.

So you can check with Vendor, if they connector for sharepoint. We are crawling the documentum files in sharepoint using their connector. But you can do more than that.

Also check this post will help you understand.

[Integrating Your Quality Management Document Control with SharePoint](http://blog.etq.com/blog/bid/94680/Integrating-Your-Quality-Management-Document-Control-with-SharePoint)

Comment: basically i am trying to integrate HP worksite with sharepoint. i know few products like ascera which does the same but i want to know the logic behind such integration and how to go about